# SSRS table with inside borders only - possible?

Tags: reporting-services, border, ssrs-tablix

I want to add to a SSRS (RDLC) report in Visual Studio 2013 a table object (Tablix) that would have borders only inside the table (between rows only, I need no border between columns), but no outside borders, like in Excel does this button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have specified the Bottom BorderStyle of an element that was inside the Tablix column with following expression:

`=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2)=1, "Dotted", "None")`

given the fact that I have allways exactly 2 rows per page inside the Tablix.

I guess that universal formula would look something like this:

`=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod numberOfRowsPerPage)=numberOfRowsPerPage-1, "Dotted", "None")`

It should remove the last border line on the page. Though this solution needs to have fixed number of rows per page in the table.